# SSIS Email Log Files and Error Handling

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, etl, sendmail

My database will have many packages that point to different folders on a shared network and grab different flat files. Every time a package is executed, I want the package to send a log file via email after completion whether it succeeds or fails.

If the package succeeds, it will send the log with how many rows imported, name of file, etc. Then the files gets deleted.

If the package fails, it well send a similar log file but with the error message. Instead of deleting the file, it will just put it in a folder called "Failed".

Is what I'm doing possible? Will I need to do this for each individual package I create, or is there another way to get a daily health report for every package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in 2 steps:

1. To send mail on package failure you must add a send email task at the `OnError` event handler:

   - [Emailing Error log file as attachments in SSIS](http://plexussql.blogspot.com/2010/01/emailing-error-log-file-as-attachments.html)
2. TO send mail on package succes, just add a send mail task at the end of the control flow

---

Also it is good to follow this article [Working with Precedence Constraints in SQL Server Integration Services](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/working-with-precedence-constraints-in-sql-server-integration-services/), it will help you to achieve this in other way (implement your own logic)

Comment: Awesome. This looks like exactly what I need. Any chance you have an article on moving/deleting files after package execution?

Comment: The same thing but you have to use a `file system task` instead of `send mail task`

Comment: @AlanPear why not accepting this answer if This looks like exactly what you need?

Comment: I was waiting to test it out. Thank you